# Getting Column not found Error at Illuminate\Database\QueryException?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-7, laravel-seeding

I am working in Laravel app and relating `users` table with `posts` table by `user_id` column. I already have `user_id` column in `posts` table. But when I run `php artisan db:seed` command, I get an error :

> `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id ' in 'field list'

**Getting below error:**

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id ' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `posts` (`user_id `, `title`, `post_image`, `content`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (11, Perferendis dolorem eum ex nesciunt., https://lorempixel.com/900/300/?54025, Unde voluptatibus praesentium unde et illum qui quo. Cupiditate pariatur aperiam fugiat perspiciatis. In atque corrupti eius ipsam saepe blanditiis minima., 1, 2020-06-28 08:54:02, 2020-06-28 08:54:02))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

  • A column was not found: You might have forgotten to run your migrations. You can run your migrations using `php artisan migrate`. 
    https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations

      +13 vendor frames 
  14  database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php:21
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save()

      +1 vendor frames 
  16  database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php:22
      Illuminate\Support\Collection::each()
```

Comment: Define the `$fillable` array and set it to protected and check if it works.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi I have tried $fillable but Same Error.

Comment: Also check the log specified: **A column was not found: You might have forgotten to run your migrations. You can run your migrations using `php artisan migrate`.**. Try executing a `php artisan migrate` and check if it reflects on the database.

Comment: It would surely not work without fillable properties and thus it needs to be mentioned there in the array. Yes the other reason could be possibly an existing migration needs to be published.

Comment: Already ran `php artisan migrate`. Even now I am running `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` command to refresh migrate and seeding every time. Same Error.

Comment: Keep the fillable intact with `user_id`.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi I can see `user_id` column in `posts` table by PhpMyAdmin tool. But getting Column not found error.

Comment: `protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'post_image', 'content'];` I have used.

Comment: Did you try `php artisan cache:clear`. Maybe cache issue.

Comment: Just now I applied this `php artisan cache:clear` command. Same Error. Even I restart my `php artisan serve`. No luck.

Comment: The last option in my opinion would be firing the `php artisan tinker` command and creating a new instance of the model `Post`. `$post= new Post();` and then setting the values one by one `$post->user_id= 1;` followed by `$post->save();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your relational function on user model there is a space after user_id. Or you need to find where do you use space after user_id.
[image: Check there is space after user_id where do you want store]

Answer (score 0):

Its because you remove `$table->timestamps();` from the column.
Add it to the column and run this query

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```